# Why do I get this error in the socket communication between Python and C#?

Tags: c#, python, sockets

I have made a socket server in Python and a socket client in C#. Whenever an event occurs in the client, it sends a string, that comprises time information(hh:mm:ss:ffff) and either a negative or positive integer, to the server and they print out the string.

The problem is that the server sometimes prints out multiple event information at the same time, in the same line. For example:

```
//C# CLIENT OUTPUT
05:42:16:5942,-8
05:42:16:5962,+1
05:42:16:5972,+1
05:42:16:5992,-1
05:42:16:6002,-1
05:42:16:6023,-1
05:42:16:6043,-1
05:42:16:7856,-7

#Python SERVER OUTPUT
05:42:16:5942,-8
05:42:16:5962,+1
05:42:16:5972,+105:42:16:5992,-1   <- the error 
05:42:16:6002,-1
05:42:16:6023,-1
05:42:16:6043,-1
05:42:16:7856,-7
```

[image]

I have no idea what causes the problem. Here' the source of the server and client.

```
#SERVER.py
from socket import *

serverSocket = socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM)
serverSocket.bind(('localhost',999))
serverSocket.listen(1)
connectionSocket, addr = serverSocket.accept()

i = 0
sentence = ""

while True:  
    sentence = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
    sentence = sentence.decode("UTF-8","ignore")

    if sentence != "end":
        print(sentence)
    else:
        print(sentence)
        connectionSocket.close()
        print("CLOSED")
        break 


//CLIENT.cs

        string sendingValue;
        static Socket sck;

        sck = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1"), 999);
        sck.Connect(localEndPoint);

        // The below runs whenever an event occurs
        string t = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh:mm:ss:ffff");
        string userCount = GetUserRealCount().Trim();

        sendingValue = t + "," + userCount;

        byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(sendingValue);
        sck.Send(data);
```

Comment: why are you double-spacing your code?

Comment: This isn't an answer, but since you're doing `print(sentence)` on the server in both cases, might as well remove that from the if...else statement and to it anyway. This would change your statement to read `if sentence == "end":` then it'll just do the closing stuff

Comment: No, I don't ;) I think the copy and paste didn't work well.

Comment: I used some unnecessary print functions to see how they communicate. I'm actually want to make a dataframe or db with the data.

Comment: Try doing print(sentence, end='\n')

Comment: Looking at your data I feel like the socket is sending a little too much to the server all at once and the server isn't understanding when to stop reading it. Add a terminator character at the end of every sending value to tell the server when to stop reading

Comment: Filip Cordas// Thank you for your answer! But I'm afraid I get the same problem.

Comment: Ortund// Do you mean something like STX/ETX? I actually refered to this(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184181/decoding-tcp-packets-using-python) and applied it to my program, but I doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: It looks like a return is missing.  Not sure why in the code this is happening.  I suspect that your receive method is dropping the return.   TCP not all the data will come at the same time.  A line can be broken into pieces.  So I suspect that you just aren't receiving some lines in one piece.

Comment: @maynull what about this print(item, end='\n',flush=True)

Comment: @Filip Cordas Thank you again! I tried it, but it yields the same problem

Comment: @jdweng Yes, I think there's some missing data, too. Do you have any recommendations on how to prevent it from happening?

Comment: I need to see the receive code.